# c++ to the top of the program

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have to write a program in C++ and am unsure on how to return to the top after an error. For example, I have the user input 2 integers, if the 2nd integer is smaller than the first i have an error stating pls enter in a number larger than the first, but from here I do not know what code to enter to have the question be asked again / send to the beginning / top of the code?

```
if (num1 > num2)
        cout << "You second number must be larger than your first number." << endl;
```

Comment: maybe using a repeat cycle or a while, then with a flag you can control if you repeat in case of error

Comment: Well, don't use [goto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto) …

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

> I do not know what code to enter to have the question be asked again / send to the beginning / top of the code?

Well **almost** always when you have that situation, you will use a `while` loop. This loops over the block if the condition is **true**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    int num1;
    int num2;

    do {

        std::cout << "What is first num? ";
        std::cin >> num1;

        std::cout << "What is second num? ";
        std::cin >> num2;

    } while (num1 < num2);
}
```

Basically, what happens is first you have to declare the integers `num1` and `num2`. Then you have a `do while` loop! Well this executes the code in the `do` block before checking for the condition! First we ask for the two user inputs, then we check for the condition.  Let's look at the condition carefully:

```
 while(num1<num2)
```

This means if the first number the user entered is less than the second number, loop through the while block. The `while` block does the same thing until `num1` becomes greater than `num2`!

[**Here**](http://cpp.sh/6nbs) is a compiled version (GCC).

### Additional Exercises

[**icodecool**](http://icodecool.blogspot.com/2012/12/c-loops-solved-exercises-practice.html)

### Tutorial

[**CS_PDF**](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mrmiller/15-110/Handouts/while.pdf)

### References

[**cpprefrence**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do)

[**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0kk5few.aspx)

[**Flow Control Tutorial**](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/)

### Glossary:

**do-while loop**:

> Executes a statement repeatedly until the value of the expression becomes false. The test takes place after each iteration.
>
> Syntax
>
> attr(optional) do statement while ( expression ) ;
>   attr(C++11) -   any number of attributes
>   expression  -   any expression which is contextually convertible to bool. This expression is evaluated after each iteration, and if it yields false, the loop is exited.
>       statement   -   any statement, typically a compound statement, which is the body of the loop

Comment: if (num1 > num2)
        cout << "You second number must be larger than your first number." << endl; 
 while(num < num2)
      cout << "You second number must be larger than your first number." << endl;

didn't work

Comment: @helpcodepls Can you look at my new code please? The previous one is outdated

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cout << "Enter number 2: ";
cin >> num2;

while (num1 > num2) {
    cout << "You second number must be larger than your first number." << endl;
    cout << "Enter number 2: ";
    cin >> num2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;

do
{
    cout << "num1: ";
    cin >> num1;

    cout << "num2: ";
    cin >> num2;

    if(num2 < num1)
        cout << "error num2 is smaler than num1" << endl;
}while(num2 < num1);
```